Hide navigation bar at AOSP codebase level without touching custom navigationbar application for Automative application
I have an automative application where I dont have access to application layer (custom application like navigation bar etc). Custom navigation bar has been developed. I want to disable this custom navigationbar from AOSP level without touching the custom application when keyboard is visible.

Hi Aman, the Android Navigation bar is a part of the SystemUI! Not a separate app.
